# why we use "@" while inserting or updating or deleting data in sql table

Tags: c#, sql, sqlparameter

I just want to know why we use   "@" while inserting or updating or deleting data in sql table, as I used @name like below.

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fname", txtfname.Text));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, no offense to the posters before me but I will try to explain it to you as simple as possible, so even a 7 year old understands it. :)

From my experience '**@**' in **.SQL** is used when you are **"just not making it clear what exact data type or exact name will be used"**. "**Later**" you are pointing out what the exact value of '@' is.

Like, say, someone has developed some huge .SQL query which contains, say, the name of every person who has received it.

```
SELECT column_name,column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name = @YOURNAME;

@YOURNAME = 'John Doe';
```

So, in this case, it's easier for everyone to just write their name at @YOURNAME and it will automatically convert the query to (upon launch):

```
SELECT column_name,column_name FROM table_name WHERE column_name = 'John Doe';
```

P.S: I am sorry for my syntax errors and incorrect terminology but I am sure you should have understood it by now. :)

Comment: Your example of variable usage doesn't show a way that a variable can actually be used. After `where` you need a condition, you can't just use a variable, or a literal value. You would need something like for example `... where column_name = @YOURNAME`.

Answer (score 4):

See: [SqlParameter.ParameterName Property - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.parametername.aspx)

> The ParameterName is specified in the form **@paramname**. You must
>   set ParameterName before executing a SqlCommand that relies on
>   parameters.

`@` is used by the `SqlCommand` so that the value of the parameter **can be differentiatd in the Command Text**

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from yourTable where ID = @ID", conn);
                                                                  ^^^^^^^
                                                   //This identifies the parameter
```

If `@` is not provided with the parameter name then it is added. Look at the following source code, [(taken from here)](http://www.dotnetframework.org/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/ndp/fx/src/Data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlParameter@cs/1305376/SqlParameter@cs)

```
 internal string ParameterNameFixed {
            get {
                string parameterName = ParameterName;
                if ((0 < parameterName.Length) && ('@' != parameterName[0])) {
                    parameterName = "@" + parameterName;
                }
                Debug.Assert(parameterName.Length <= TdsEnums.MAX_PARAMETER_NAME_LENGTH, "parameter name too long");
                return parameterName;
            }
        }
```

**EDIT:**

If you don't use `@` sign with the parameter then consider the following case.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * from yourTable WHERE ID = ID";
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", 1);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
            }
        }
```

The above will fetch all the records, since this will translate into `SELECT * from yourTable WHERE 1=1`, If you use `@` above for the parameter `ID`, you will get only the records against `ID =1`

Answer (score 0):

Variables and parameters in SQL Server are preceded by the @ character.

Example:

```
create procedure Something
  @Id int,
  @Name varchar(100)
as
...
```

When you create parameter objects in the C# code to communicate with the database, you also specify parameter names with the @ character.

(There is an undocumented feature in the SqlParameter object, which adds the @ to the parameter name if you don't specify it.)

Comment: can we use another char instead of @ ?

Comment: @Gaurav: No, the @ is what's used for parameters. What do you want to use instead, and why?

Comment: I just want to know. That's it nothing more.